# Bitcoind has too slow API call performance on large wallets

Tags: bitcoind, api, json-rpc

Bitcoind (bitcoin-0.11.2, linux32) has too slow performance when the wallet size gets bigger, i will post here some average timing behaviors.
The wallet size is 410MB.

A getbalance call requires 1.45 s in average
A sendfrom call requires 5.46 s in average
A gettransaction call requires 0.595 s in average
A getaccountaddress call requires 0.634 s in average
A move call requires 0.33 s in average

To speed up these calls i have already put the wallet into ram-fs. But its too slow again. Is there a chance that those calls will speed up with upcoming bitcoind versions?